# How can I have a button in a const object?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React.js and this is a table showing which user has which items.
I would like to have a button for each item and delete the corresponding item.
How do you have  or {FaTrash} icon in a const object?

This is my full code below

```
const columns = [
    {
        name: "Username",
        selector: "username",
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        name: "Email",
        selector: "email",
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        name: "Item",
        selector: "items",
        sortable: true,
        right: true
    },
    {
        name: "Action",
        value: <button>Edit</button>
    }
]


const Admin = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(allUsers);

    const handleRowClicked = row => {
        const updatedData = data.map(item => {
            if (row.id !== item.id) {
              return item;
            }
      
            return {
              ...item,
              toggleSelected: !item.toggleSelected
            };
          });
      
          setData(updatedData);
    }

    return ( <>
        <div className='users p-5'>
            <DataTable 
                title="Users"
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                defaultSortField="title"
                pagination
                onRowClicked={handleRowClicked}
            />
        </div>
    </> );
}
 
export default Admin;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to pass a function that returns a piece of layout with handler

```
 {
    name: "Action",
    actionRenderer: ({ index, item }) => {
      return (
       <button onClick={() => onhandle(item)}>
           ActionName <!--or icon component-->
       </button>
       )
    }
 },
```

Than you need to create `<DataTableRow>` component wich will render each object in your columns array. Somewhere in the `<DataTableRow>` you will be able to access to actionRenderer and your data item:

```
<div>{actionColumn.actionRenderer({ index, item })}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! What is actionColumn tho?

Comment: it is just for example (if you decide to create the component for each column). In your case actionRenderer is a child of columns[4]